# How get authorization in spring security with multivalued attributes CAS

Tags: spring-security, attributes, single-sign-on, cas

I'm having problems of how to read CAS ticket permissions on spring security when I multivalued attributes, for example: ROLE = [x, y, z]. I want to read permission "y" of the ROLE, how do? What if I have ROLE = [x = [a], y = [b], z = [c]], how do I read permission "a" within "x" which is part of ROLE? I do not know how to do this using the hasRole ('') of the spring security.